# Is there a way to pre-filter a powerBI report server side?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have uploaded a report, and using the .net SDK I've embedded said report into my website. However we show private data for many organizations. If I edit the reports iframe url to filter the report by the users org id so they can only see data for their organization then that ends up being a URL you can edit in javascript on the client side so a use could put another id there and view some other organizations data.

Is there any way possible to filter the data a report shows before it is sent client side?

I know you can edit the report file it'self but if you have hundreds of organizations, you'd need 100 copies of the same report which is obviously a maintenance and upkeep nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the "Row Level Security" (RLS) feature for this requirement.  Basically you set up roles, assign users to them and assign DAX expressions to them to filter the data.

There's a good explanation of it here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-rls/

The most efficient design of RLS (from a coding and admin perspective) is if you can feed in a username variable and filter your data by that (as shown in that example).

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting that info from.  It's not on the link I provided.  I don't believe your quotes are relevant to this scenario.

Comment: Wow I'm sorry I deleted that comment cause you were right and the quotes were from another tab I had open describing how to do RLS but it was using pbi service not embedded. Your method seems to work like a charm thank you.  For anyone else finding this there are a few ways to use embedded and by using the APPToken Method you can specify what you want BI to see the user as instead of letting it garner this from some azure login. Basically like a forced or spoofed login Very smooth idea. Thanks!